# How can I hide a <div> and have it show only when a <textarea> has focus?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagedown

I'm using the same editor as Stack Overflow and the HTML looks something like this with multiple editors on a page:

```
<pagedown-admin id="modal-data-solution-1">
   <div>
      <div>
         Menu
      </div>
   </div>
   <textarea>
         ABC
   </textarea>
</pagedown-admin>
<pagedown-admin id="modal-data-solution-2">
   <div>
      <div>
         Menu
      </div>
   </div>
   <textarea>
         ABC
   </textarea>
</pagedown-admin>
```

Is there a way that I could hide the `<div>` that contains the menu and have it show only when the `<textarea>` has focus. Note that I'm not using jQuery so it would need to be a vanilla JavaScript solution. I'm just not sure where to start trying to code something like that.

Comment: You should start by learning how to hide/show elements with JS. Then, learn about handling events like `focus`. Then join both knowledges! :)

Comment: Take a look at this question for adding native event handlers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563258/blur-and-focus-event-in-native-javascript

Comment: `Jquery` is nothing but `Javascript`. It takes pain out of writing long `Javascript` syntax statements and makes you achieve more with fewer lines of code. Why not use it?

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri If a user doesn't want a jQuery solution then they don't want one. Plain and simple. Why try to force your beliefs on others? There are many situations where jQuery is unnecessary. See: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a generic solution, that will work with multiple menus based on your markup. The JavaScript could be improved, but it will give you an idea, how to solve it.

**HTML**

```
<pagedown-admin>
    <div>
        <div class="off">Menu</div>
   </div>
   <textarea>
         ABC
   </textarea>
</pagedown-admin>
```

**CSS**

```
.off {
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var tas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

for (var i = 0, j = tas.length; i < j; ++i) {
    tas[i].onfocus = function() {
        var e = this.parentNode.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
        e.classList.toggle('off');
    }

    tas[i].onblur = function() {
        var e = this.parentNode.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
        e.classList.toggle('off');
    }
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/10qs8Ln7/)

Answer (score 2):

Use **onfocus** event when you focus the textarea and **onblur** event when you are losing the focus on it :

```
function hideDiv(){
   document.getElementById("divID").style.display = 'none';   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8zm3rw7p/4/

UPDATED :

http://jsfiddle.net/8zm3rw7p/9/

Answer (score 2):

You could attach to the native event handlers a function like it is done in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563258/blur-and-focus-event-in-native-javascript), and show/hide the menu.

```js
(function() {
    var elm = document.getElementById("textarea");
    elm.addEventListener('blur', handler, false);
    elm.addEventListener('focus', handler, false);

    function handler(event) {
        if (event.type === "blur") {
            document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "";
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<pagedown-admin id="modal-data-solution-2">
   <div id="menu" style="display: none">
      <div>
         Menu
      </div>
   </div>
   <textarea id="textarea">
         ABC
   </textarea>
</pagedown-admin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the example from the question @AlejandroC mentioned, here is one viable solution

```js
(function() {
    document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('blur', handler, false);
    document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('focus', handler, false);
    document.getElementById('second').addEventListener('blur', handler, false);
    document.getElementById('second').addEventListener('focus', handler, false);

    function handler(event) {
        if (event.type === "blur") {
            document.getElementById(this.id+'Div').style.display="none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(this.id+'Div').style.display="block";
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<pagedown-admin id="modal-data-solution-1">
   <div>
      <div id='firstDiv' style='display:none'>
         Menu
      </div>
   </div>
   <textarea id='first'>
         ABC
   </textarea>
</pagedown-admin>
<pagedown-admin id="modal-data-solution-2">
   <div>
      <div id='secondDiv' style='display:none'>
         Menu
      </div>
   </div>
   <textarea id='second'>
         ABC
   </textarea>
</pagedown-admin>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the structure will always be the same, you can use this method for efficiency.

Select all of the menus using [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then iterate through them with a [`for()` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

In each iteration, set `display: none` to hide the element, then attach an [`onfocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus) event handler and an [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur) event handler to its [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling).

In the `onfocus` event handler, remove the modified `display` property from the focused element's [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling)

In the `onblur` event handler, set `display: none` on the focused element's `previousElementSibling`

---

```js
var menus = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=modal-data-solution] > div'), 
    l = menus.length, i;

for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    menus[i].style.display = "none";
    menus[i].nextElementSibling.onfocus = handleFocus;
    menus[i].nextElementSibling.onblur = handleBlur;
}
    
function handleFocus() {
    this.previousElementSibling.style.display = '';
}

function handleBlur() {
    this.previousElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<pagedown-admin id="modal-data-solution-1" style="display: block;">
   <div>
      <div>
         Menu
      </div>
   </div>
   <textarea>
         ABC
   </textarea>
</pagedown-admin>
<pagedown-admin id="modal-data-solution-2" style="display: block;">
   <div>
      <div>
         Menu
      </div>
   </div>
   <textarea>
         ABC
   </textarea>
</pagedown-admin>
```