# textarea hide buttons onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `textarea` for the user to type something and it has a `cancel` and a `submit` button as part of it.

How can I make it so that the `cancel` and `submit` button only appears when the user clicks inside the `textarea`? (using javascript, no jquery please)

I have attempted using this javascript function:

```
function setButtons(writingtext) {
    if (writingtext) {
        document.getElementById('cfm').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('cancel').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('cfm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('cancel').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

When the user clicks the text area, it would be `onClick="setButtons(True)"` -> displays the buttons.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach here. Sorry, really new to this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hide a <div> and have it show only when a <textarea> has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188447/how-can-i-hide-a-div-and-have-it-show-only-when-a-textarea-has-focus)

Comment: Look in to `addEventListener` and passing the "focus" property. Give it a go. If you struggle then show your code and we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have control over your html you can do it with just `css` sniping the next sibling at `:focus` like this:

```css
div {display:none;}
textarea:focus + div {display:block;}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<div>
  <input type="submit">
  <input type="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only a simple example to show the buttons on focus. If you want to hide them, I think you will be able to manage that solution.

If all you want to do is show the buttons when the text area is focused, use the CSS-only solution. However, I'm guessing you'll want to keep them for a bit or do some extra pre-processing before the submit, in which case you should use the javascript option.

```js
document.querySelector("#textarea").addEventListener("focus", function() {
    document.querySelector("#submit").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector("#cancel").style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
button {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign an id to the textarea for example `text` and then use

```
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('focus', function(){
  document.getElementById('cfm').style.display = 'block'
document.getElementById('cancel').style.display = 'block'
})

// Hide when blur (when not focused)

document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('blur', function(){
  document.getElementById('cfm').style.display = 'none'

  document.getElementById('cancel').style.display = 'none'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
`onfocus="setButtons(this)"` instead of `onClick`

```js
function setButtons(writingtext) {
    document.getElementById('cfm').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('cancel').style.display = 'block';
}
```